# arabic digits are shown instead of English

Tags: android, format, android-dateutils

I've a text view. in onCreate I set its text to be:

```
textView.setText(DateUtils.formatElapsedTime(162)) // 162 seconds
```

Because the app is in arabic, its date is written as: "٠٢:٤٢" while I would like to set it in ENGLISH.
How to show this number in english without letting Android change it to arabic?
I'm trying to use Locale.US somehow.

Comment: you can use this answer right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38924076/9426046)

Comment: Or this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39385917/9426046) written in java.

Comment: at your  `formatElapsedTime ` use `Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);`

Comment: How? formatElapsedTime receives 1 long parameter(long elapsedSeconds) OR 2 parameters(StringBuilder recycler, long elapsedSeconds)